# How can I return the closest left and right child of a single node in simple binary tree?

Tags: python, class, binary-tree

I got a problem with my code, here it is : I want to return the closest left and right child of a node, but whenever I try to, it returns me ALL the children of this node.

I separated the code in two files, one contains the binary tree class (not BST, just a simple BT), and the other contains tkinter things, that suppose to show the node and his children. See below for the code, and  sorry for some of the parts in french, if u need words to be translated i'm up.

binary tree file :

```
class ArbreBinaire:
    def __init__(self, valeur):
        self.valeur = valeur
        self.enfant_gauche = None
        self.enfant_droit = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.valeur}, ({self.enfant_gauche}, {self.enfant_droit})"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ3Gr.png)

    def insert_gauche(self, valeur):
        if self.enfant_gauche == None:
            self.enfant_gauche = ArbreBinaire(valeur)
        else:
            new_node = ArbreBinaire(valeur)
            new_node.enfant_gauche = self.enfant_gauche
            self.enfant_gauche = new_node

    def insert_droit(self, valeur):
        if self.enfant_droit == None:
            self.enfant_droit = ArbreBinaire(valeur)
        else:
            new_node = ArbreBinaire(valeur)
            new_node.enfant_droit = self.enfant_droit
            self.enfant_droit = new_node

    def get_valeur(self):
        return self.valeur

    def get_gauche(self):
        return self.enfant_gauche

    def get_droit(self):
        return self.enfant_droit
```

tkinter and main parts file :

```
from arb import ArbreBinaire
from tkinter import *

def classe_arb():
    global racine, b_node, f_node, c_node, g_node, h_node
    arb = ArbreBinaire
    racine = ArbreBinaire('A')
    racine.insert_gauche('B')
    racine.insert_droit('F')

    b_node = racine.get_gauche()
    b_node.insert_gauche('C')
    b_node.insert_droit('D')

    f_node = racine.get_droit() 
    f_node.insert_gauche('G')
    f_node.insert_droit('H')

    c_node = b_node.get_gauche()
    c_node.insert_droit('E')

    g_node = f_node.get_gauche()
    g_node.insert_gauche('I')

    h_node = f_node.get_droit()
    h_node.insert_droit('J')
    return arb

def accueil():
    global fenetre
    fenetre = Tk()
    fenetre.title("Bienvenue dans l'énigme du manoir")
    fenetre.geometry("1000x500")

    bt_jouer= Button(fenetre, text="Jouer", fg="green", command=lambda: valeur_bouton(1))
    bt_jouer.pack()

    bt_quitter = Button(fenetre, text="Quitter", fg="red", command=quit)
    bt_quitter.pack()

    fenetre.mainloop()

def jeu(phrase, rep1, rep2): 
    global run
    run = True
    while run == True:
        global wd_jeu
        wd_jeu = Tk()
        wd_jeu.title("L'énigme du manoir")
        wd_jeu.geometry("1000x500")
        
        label = Label(wd_jeu, text=phrase, bg = "blue", fg = "white", font = "Castellar")
        label.pack()

        option1 = Button(wd_jeu, text=rep1, fg="black")
        option1.pack()

        option2 = Button(wd_jeu, text=rep2, fg="black")
        option2.pack()
        wd_jeu.mainloop() 
        
        
def valeur_bouton(nb):
    if nb == 0:
        None
    if nb == 1:
        fenetre.destroy()
        jeu('Hello', racine.valeur, racine.enfant_gauche)

classe_arb()
accueil()
```

Okay, so basically the problem is in the last function : "racine.valeur" and "racine.enfant_gauche". The first one works very well, it returns me the node with no problem. The second one "racine.enfant_gauche" is supposed to return the closest left child of the A node (B in this case), but it prints me all the children  : "B, (C, (None, E, (None, None)), D, (None, None))".

I tried many things like this, like getting the value with the method "get_gauche" but it doesnt work as well. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your `__str__`  prints the current node and all its descendants, so this is expected. If you don't want to print the descendants, why did you code it like that?

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` method is called recursively because the format string `f"{self.valeur}, ({self.enfant_gauche}, {self.enfant_droit})"` will use the `__str__` method of each child to resolve the embedded text.

To avoid the recursion, you could define method to get values of the left and right (e.g. `valeur_gauche()`, `valeur_droite()`) and use those instead in the format string.  You could also get the values within your `__str__` function and assemble the resulting string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `racine.enfant_gauche` evaluates to an instance of `ArbreBinaire`, and so when you pass it as argument to `jeu` and pass it to the `Button` constructor, the node's `__str__` method will be called to retrieve the string that must be printed. This `__str__` method will create a string representation that includes all descendants.

The expression `racine.valeur` on the other hand is a string (a single letter in your example), and so when you pass that to `jeu`, which passes it to the `Button` constructor, it will render as that string (as expected).

If you want the same behaviour for the left child, you should also take the `.valeur` attribute, like so:

```
jeu('Hello', racine.valeur, racine.enfant_gauche.valeur)
```